# Rust Destructuring directly inside print without using any extra variables

Tags: rust, destructuring

I have an enum and a variable,

```
enum Message {
    Write(String),
}

let msg = Message::Write("hi".to_string());
```

I want to print the String inside "msg". By destructuring directly inside the print macro, without using any extra variables, something like this ,

```
print!("{Message::Write(:?)}", msg); // This won't work
```

or like this

```
print!("{}", msg:<Message::Write(String)>); // This won't work either
```

Comment: What you are asking is simply impossible, you can't access a field a an enum variant without destructuring it. You should probably implement `Display` or `Debug` if you want to make it easy to print your enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the content of any complex structure by destructuring:

```
let msg = Message::Write("hi".to_string());
println!("{}", { let Message::Write(m) = msg; m });
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b993728e3124b5746466023d8b442fff)

Answer (score 0):

You can print the content of any complex structure or enum as per your preference by implementing the `Display` trait.

```rust
use std::fmt;
enum Message {
    Write(String),
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Message {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Message::Write(s) => write!(f, "{}", s),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let msg = Message::Write("hi".to_string());
    println!("{}", msg);
}
```